# fail to pass argument to self-written function

Tags: c, memory-management

i write a merge sort program. But it came to segmentation fault (core dumped) when it run.
here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* input_array(size_t *);
void divide_and_conquer_sort(int *restrict, size_t, size_t);
int main(void){
    size_t LEN=0;
    int *array;
    array=input_array(&LEN);
    puts("Here is a sort to all array's elements from small to large:");
    divide_and_conquer_sort(array, 0, LEN-1);
    for(size_t i=0; i<LEN; i++)printf("%d\040", array[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;}


int* input_array(size_t *ptr_to_LEN){
    int *array=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    static char buf[BUFSIZ];
    void *alloc_check;
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter decimal integer arrays(use spaces key to separate every number):\n");
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", array+*ptr_to_LEN)==1)
    {
        alloc_check=realloc(array, (*ptr_to_LEN+2)*sizeof(int));
        if(alloc_check!=NULL)array=(int*)alloc_check;
        (*ptr_to_LEN)++; if(getchar()=='\n')break;
    }

    if(*ptr_to_LEN==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no number entered correctly.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return array;}


void divide_and_conquer_sort(int *restrict array, size_t left, size_t right){
    size_t middle;
    middle=(left+right)/2;
    divide_and_conquer_sort(array, left, middle);
    divide_and_conquer_sort(array, middle+1, right);

    if(left==right)return;
    int *sub_array=(int*)malloc((right-left+1)*sizeof(int));
    size_t i, j, k;
    i=left; j=middle+1; k=0;
    while(i<=middle && j<=right)
    {
        if(*(array+i)<*(array+j))
        {
            *(sub_array+k)=*(array+i);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            *(sub_array+k)=*(array+j);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<=middle)
    {
        *(sub_array+k)=*(array+i);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=right)
    {
        *(sub_array+k)=*(array+j);
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for(k=0; k<=right-left; k++)
        *(array+k+left)=*(sub_array+k);
    return;
}
```

the `input_array` is an array input function. It gets the address of `LEN` and modified `LEN` value by its address. Actually `LEN` is the length of input array. but when i want to pass `LEN-1` to `divide_and_conquer_sort`, it failed!

i used gdb debugger that told me

```
0x00right=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7eefc8>)
```

why `LEN-1` can't be serve as argument in `divide_and_conquer_sort`?

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans (the compiler does not care) 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   Amongst other things, this means things like: `j++;}` should have the `'}' on a second line.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `alloc_check=realloc(array, (*ptr_to_LEN+2)*sizeof(int));
    if(alloc_check!=NULL)array=(int*)alloc_check;`  1) a `void*` can be assigned to any pointer, so no need to cast.  casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) when `realloc()` fails, do NOT continue on as if everything is alright (it's not alright) instead, call `perror( "realloc failed" );` then cleanup, then call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Similar considerations exist for a call to `malloc()` and/or `calloc()`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `setbuf(stdin, NULL);` and `setvbuf(stdin, buf, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);`  These statements are rarely ever a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish with these statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursing indefinitely and have exhausted the available stack space. That's why the debugger can't read the address of `right`, which is on the stack.

Just from looking at the code you can see what the problem is: every call to `divide_and_conquer_sort` *always* results in two more calls to `divide_and_conquer_sort`. There needs to be some kind of end condition where you return without calling `divide_and_conquer_sort`, for example when `left` and `right` are the same. (It's there! Just in the wrong place.)

Comment: so if i put `if(left==right)return;` in a wrong place. where am i supposed to put it?

Comment: At the top of the function, before you recursively call `divide_and_conquer_sort`.